# referencing an item from enumerate in an article calss

Tags: cross-referencing, enumerate, enumitem

I misspoke I meant I used enumerate not cases sorry.

Is it possible to reference a case?

I have `\begin{enumerate}` and then cases 1 to 4 where each case is a rather detailed.

I would like the refer the reader back to case 2 where the solving a complex integral took place since the only difference in case 2 and 4 is tan and tanh due to the changing of the variable e.

I tried labeling the case but that doesn't work.

A more reasonable example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, hyperref}


\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item[Case 1:]
x
\item[Case 2:]
\label{case2}
xx
\item[Case 4:]
 case~\ref{case2} 

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

As you can see there is no reference to click after the word case:

[image]

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have added a very minimal example.

Comment: Oh `\label` works automatically in `enumerate` It doesn't in `cases` which was what your original question indicated.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I noticed the error in my question and noted it in the op but the label isn't working when I compile the document it just says case (then a blank) where the reference should be.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle see png image.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I ran it 3 times! and then again when that didn't work and then again.

Comment: That example isn't very minimal (-1 only second time I've so voted)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle it produces the error though.  My extremely minimal didn't appease you so I gave you the 5% of the actual code that causes the issue and I took out some stuff to make it smaller too.

Comment: I just deleted stuff in your example while still seeing the hyperref warning You could easily have done that.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle that is about the same example I started with.

Comment: It is not at all like the example you started with: it reproduces the error, which makes it easy to fix, see my updated answer.

Comment: @dustin: Have you ever worked with [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem)?

Comment: I removed the downvote but _please_ make a more reasonable example next time.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I was under the impression the re-indexing of the item in enumerate wouldn't change how it functioned that is why I made the first really simple example and then the full example since I didn't see that detail as the problem.

Comment: but if you had _run_ your small example you would have seen that the reference worked,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The MWE as posted produces

[image]

If you don't get that, check your log file for something strange....

Using the updated MWE you see all (automatic) numbering is suppressed so there is nothing to label You should never number "by hand". Just use a list and customise the display, Here I use `enumerate` although `enumitem` is newer with more features.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, hyperref,enumerate}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[{Case} 1:]
\item
x
\item
\label{case2}
xx
\item
 case~\ref{case2} 

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: in the log file, I have `Package hyperref Warning: Suppressing empty link on input line 1893.` and `LaTeX Warning: There were multiply-defined labels.`

Comment: Your MWE only has one `\label` how can it have multiple anything? Is that really the log from the MWE as posted? It also doesn't load hyperref

Comment: that is from the actual document.  I found the multiple issue it had nothing to with the current problem.  The only warning is the suppressing piece what does that mean? That MWE isn't the real thing I am working on.  I just supplied that since you asked.

Comment: You are obviously not running your own MWE, since that doesn't load `hyperref`, doesn't have 1893 lines, has only one label (and the text in the image you have uploaded is different). In your case, the MWE needs to be a minimal *non*-working example. Long and short of it is that your MWE shows that `\label` and `\ref` will work, and there must be some error in your actual document: it's probably a typo in your labels or references. Preparing a MWE which shows the problem will probably reveal it!

Comment: @PaulStanley as per the op that will be 4 pages long and that will just be the portion related to the issue.  The actually document is 40 pages.

Comment: @dustin please don't waste people's time. the whole point is that you generate an example that shows the problem. Your MWE shows \label/ref works, so if you have some example where it doesn't work you have done something wrong in some code you have not shown us.

Comment: @dustin you need to create the MWE _from_ your original document. Copy it to another file and begin deleting stuff (but make sure the error persists) until you have a minimal version that shows the error.

Comment: @dustin No. The idea is that you start from your document and cut it down to a few lines while preserving the fact that it doesn't work. Most likely while doing that you will find out yourself which code is wrong.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle what is up with the 1, 2, and 3 where the a should be in case?

Comment: @dustin sorry you need `{Case}` as a top level `a` gets replaced by `a` `b` `c` ... I updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you're at on this, but what you ask can be done.  Apologize if I have missed the thrust of your question.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item A \label{a}
\item B \label{b}
\item C \label{c}
\end{enumerate}

Please refer to Items~\ref{b} \& \ref{c}.

\end{document}
```